# PHP - Writing to a file won't output anything at all, path does exist

Tags: php, server, filesystems

I've been trying to write code to register an account in PHP. I've looked it up over and over and over again, but this problem doesn't seem to have a solution.

Here's my code:

```
file_put_contents("http://".strtolower(gethostname())."/member/users.txt", $_GET["username"] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: You can't put contents through http like that. It would be very insecure if you could. You can only create and store file in the file system. Since you use `gethostname()`, I'm guessing you're trying to save the file on the same machine as the code? Then use a proper file path, like: `file_put_contents('/local/filepath/to/member/users.text', ....)`

Comment: Oh. Hmm.. I seem to remember putting through HTTP just fine a while ago, I'll try this and see if it works.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, can you post that as an answer so I can mark it? Using /var/www/html/member/users.txt instead worked perfectly.

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put contents through `http` like that. It would be very insecure if you could. You can only create and store file in the file system.

Since you use `gethostname()`, I'm assuming that you're trying to save the file on the same machine as the code.

Use a proper file path, like:

```
file_put_contents('/local/filepath/to/member/users.text', ....)
```

You might have mixed it up with `file_get_contents()` that can get the contents using http if you've allowed it in your php.ini.